# Android: Can you be selective around what Activities make up a Task set

Tags: android, android-activity

Activity "A" displays the apps core Entity which is a Product. From Activity "A" you can open child activities such as:

- Activity F - Product Order History
- Activity G - Product Reviews
- Activity H - Similar Products

We only ever want one instance of the Product activity in the back stack.

I know that I can use the Intent Flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when opening an instance of "A" and Android will look for a previous instance of "A" and if found "all of the other activities on top of it will be closed" and that instance of "A" will be used. This is how we maintain only 1 instance of "A" in the back stack. It works well and means A and any child activities such as F,G and H are closed.

The trouble is that sometimes we might open a product search Activity from Activity "A". Logically that is not a child of "A".

Is there a way of telling Android that the product search activity is not to be closed by the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`\ `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` combo?

Comment: why not pass integer values as extras and do specific actions manually according to integer values?

Comment: extra actions such as?

Comment: There is no way to do this in a single task. It also wouldn't make any sense. The task stack is a stack of activities. If A starts ZZ (which isn't a child of A), what activity is then started (on top of ZZ) that wants to go back to A and remove all of its children? If ZZ is on top of A, then it would need to clear ZZ to get back to A. Your navigation sounds flawed. Either that, or you want 2 separate tasks (which you can do, but this has more compliations). Please explain your navigation in more detail so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put unrelated activities into a separate task. Just set `taskAffinity=""` in the `<activity>` declaration in the manifest for those activities, and make sure that you specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in any `Intent` that you use to launch those activities.

Warning: If you have multiple tasks, you should consider either creating a separate app icon for the other task(s), and/or prevent the other task(s) from showing up in the list of recent tasks. Otherwise, the user will be confused if he shows the list of recent tasks and sees 2 of them that look like your app.

Comment: What is the "List of recent tasks"? Is that similar to the List of running apps?

Comment: WHen you long press the HOME button, or use the "recent tasks" button (on different devices it is a different hardware button), this shows the "list of recent tasks".